# Foreign key vs string

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have to create a table to map some strings that are my input, to the result value that is a value that I can choose, like an id (or string).
So, to make an example, I have an excel file made of a not normalized list of names, that are all the possible values that I can expect:

- "audi A4"
- "Audi A6"
- "audi a6"
- "ford focus"
- "my beautiful car from Henry F."

And manually (luckily there're not so much elements), I have to associate them an ID or an identificative TAG that I can choose, for example I'm creating a column `TAG` and chose as values "AUDI" and "FORD":

| description | tag |
| --- | --- |
| audi A4 | AUDI |
| Audi A6 | AUDI |
| audi A6 | AUDI |
| ford focus | FORD |
| my beautiful car from Henry F. | FORD |

There's no way to automatically discover the tag, so I have to do it one by one.
My question is if the column `TAG` is ok or if it's better to put in the tag column an integer as foreign key to another table that will be mapped as:

| id | tag_description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AUDI |
| 2 | FORD |

Do I really need this associative table?

I was thinking to uppercase all strings values of `description`, so I will not have both "Audi A6" and "audi a6", and after from my Java code will be easy uppercase the input and check it with the column `description`, do you have others suggests?

Comment: No I will not need in future to store other vendor infos. I just need the vendor id to process a description and assign it an unique vendor id value.

Comment: Having worked for a motor vehicle department, and working on migrating some code + data, we found an amazing number of misspellings of car manufacturer names: transposed letters, adjacent key presses and just plain bad spelling. There were tens of thousands of misspelled mfgr names over a 40 year period of clerks entering data (Chevrolet, for example, had 126 different spellings) of cars, motorcycles, trucks and boats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your examples indicate the tag is nothing but a vendor id (or brand name), so better call the extra column `VendorId`, not just `Tag`.

Now it should become apparent your question is essentially "Do I need a separate table for all vendors?". That is something you need to answer for yourself: in case you need to store or display more vendor information than the vendor id, a second table would be useful. Otherwise, it would probably be overdesign.

Another point is the datatype (integer vs string). In case the vendor or brand can change afterwards, a separate table with an integer foreign key will allow mutation of vendor names more easily. Otherwise  I would stick to the simple "one table" approach.